# Get the max length of SQL Server column using an array

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have four columns in my table `Surname`, `FirstName`, `MiddleName`, `CurrAddress`. Is there a way that I can store column names dynamically using an array and get the max length of each column? Say for example out of the four fields I only need the `Surname` and `FirstName` maximum lengths. My code below will only display one column per transaction. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getColumnLength]
     @colval nvarchar(50),
     @tblval nvarchar(50)
 AS
 BEGIN
     SELECT 
         character_maximum_length as 'Max Length'
     FROM 
         information_schema.columns
     WHERE 
         column_name = @colval 
         AND table_name = @tblval
 END
 GO
```

Comment: If you are filter with `column_name=@colval` then it will return one column per the transaction. Do you really want to get the maximum length field of the table?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a table-valued parameter in place of an array see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb510489(v=sql.110).aspx

Example by microsoft did not work for me but the following code does

```
USE AdventureWorksdw2012;
GO

/* Create a table type. */
drop type t1
go
CREATE TYPE t1 AS TABLE 
( tabname CHAR(50)
, colname char(50) );
GO

/* Create a procedure to receive data for the table-valued parameter. */
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo. usp_InsertProductionLocation
    @TVP [db_datareader].[t1] readonly
    AS 

 BEGIN
     SELECT 
         character_maximum_length as 'Max Length'
     FROM 
         @TVP
     join information_schema.columns on table_name = tabname and column_name = colname

 END
 GO

/* Declare a variable that references the type. */
DECLARE @TVP AS t1;

/* Add data to the table variable. */
insert into @TVP values ('dimcustomer','title'),('dimcustomer','firstname')

/* Pass the table variable data to a stored procedure. */
EXEC usp_InsertProductionLocation @TVP;
GO
```

Problem with microsofts's example seemed to be that t1 needs to be fully qualified within stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You have a native function for this:

```
     select COL_LENGTH('TABLENAME', 'COLUMNNAME')
```